# Command line arguments in C, cant understand its behaviour

Tags: c, command-line

I've the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int a = argv[1]?atoi(argv[1]):10;
    int b = argv[2]?atoi(argv[2]):20;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

If I do not provide any command line inputs, the values in "a" and "b"
should be 10 and 20 respectively, but what happens instead is "a" gets value as 10 whereas "b" gets 0.
I cant understand why this is happening, since I am doing exactly same
thing in both cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you are invoking Undefined Behaviour. If no command line args are provided then the code MUST NOT access those `arg` entries. They are not all guaranteed to be NULL in that case. Only `argv[argc]` is defined to be NULL by the C standard.

Comment: In the third and fourth lines, try changing `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to `(argc>1)` and `(argc>2)`

Comment: I tried checking if argv[1] and argv[2] are null, turns out argv[2] is not null even when I dont provide any inputs on command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime (often thru [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) & [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29)) guarantees (per C99 or POSIX standards) that (for `main`'s arguments `argc` & `argv`) :

- `argc` is positive
- `argv` is a valid non `NULL` pointer to an array of `argc+1` pointers
- `argv[argc]` is the `NULL` pointer
- for each `i` between 0 and `argc-1` included, `argv[i]` is a (valid non `NULL`) pointer to a zero-terminated string
- hence access to `argv[j]`  with `j>argc` (or `j<0`) is [***undefined behavior***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) - so explaining what happens is only possible by diving into implementation details...
- the valid `argv[i]` are not [pointer aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), so if `i` & `j` are both  between 0 and `argc-1` included, and `i` != `j`, `argv[i]` != `argv[j]`

therefore, your code is wrong when `argc==1` because accessing `argv[2]` is forbidden (UB).

You should code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int a = (argc>1)?atoi(argv[1]):10;
    int b = (argc>2)?atoi(argv[2]):20;
```

Be *very* [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of undefined behavior (see also the references [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289020/40065)). Sadly, a program with UB might *sometimes* appear to "work" (that is might not crash). But at other times bad things may happen. So you should imagine the worst.

Answer (score 6):

> If I do not provide any command line inputs, the values in "a" and "b"
>   should be 10 and 20 respectively.

No, if you don't provide any command-line inputs, you're accessing beyond the end of the `argv` array and *anything can happen* (including your program crashing and burning).

Your checks should be:

```
int a = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 10;
int b = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 20;
```

That's what `argc` is for, to tell you how many entries `argv` has in it that you can access.