# where to call main function (dev c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, dev-c++

I'm very new to c++. I have a standard dev c++ windows application winapi, but it doesnt get formatted well here on stackoverflow. 
So here you can see it:
 [see here](https://codeshare.io/ayJqq0)

but my question is, where am i supposed to do the main function? if i just create a new `int main()`, the window doesn't come up at all. 
am i supposed to do it in the `WinMain()` function?

any suggestions?

EDIT: I just found out dev c++ doesnt have a compiler.

Comment: If you're making a console program the entry point is main, if a Windows app it is WinMain. Unless you go out of your way to change the entry point that function is called automatically for you. You should learn to post code here, a link that expires doesn't help anyone looking at this question later.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Do I have to create a new function or use the existing one?

Comment: If you start your programs with an empty file and then write code you'd need to provide the proper function. If you're copy/pasting it depends on what those contents are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) is *not* a compiler, but an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (that is, a glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)). Your compiler is probably some variant of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) compiler) like [MINGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW).

In standard C99 (or C11) or C++11, the entry point of your (command line) program is `main`.

You need to *define* such a function, and the runtime system (e.g. [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) on Unix) will call it.

You should not *call* that `main` function. Its prefered signature should be

```
int main(int argc, char**argv);
```

You probably should run your program in some terminal emulator. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498253/841108) are some properties of `argc` and `argv` (imposed by the C or C++ standards).

Any other entry point (e.g. `WinMain`) could be Windows specific and might require some specific compiler options.

You would compile a C program using `gcc`, and a C++ program using `g++`. I strongly recommend enabling all warnings & debug info by using `-Wall -Wextra -g` flags to that `gcc` or `g++` compiler. You may want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

For GUI programs in C++, I would recommend [Qt](http://qt.io/) (it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and multi-platform).

Comment: somehow i got him to compile using g++.exe. compiling result: 
  `Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Output Filename: C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Project1.exe
- Output Size: 1,83782863616943 MiB
- Compilation Time: 6,01s
`